# Javascript - Maintaining a single JSON array for 5 select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How can I have a json array `[{k1:"v1"},{k2:"v2"},{k3:"v3"},{k4:"v4"}.........]` populated in 5 select fields so that it is unique always.

i.e. if I select some value in field1, that value would not be shown in other select fields.
Again if I change values in any field, other select fields should be affected accordingly.

Any guide or code snippet will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i disable the selected option. If it works for you, Then you can easily do something like this:

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/3cVqL/2/

```
$('#vendor_select_from').change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this)[0].id + 2;
    $('#' + selected).attr('disabled','disabled')
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');

    var $select2 = $('#vendor_select_from2');
    if(selected == $(':selected', $select2)[0].id) {
        $select2.val('');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

HTML

```
<select name="vendor" id="vendor_select_from">
    <option  value="Apple" id="id0">Apple</option>
    <option  value="Vector Resources, Inc" id="id1">Vector Resources, Inc</option>
    <option  value="Dell, Inc." id="id2">Dell, Inc.</option>
    <option  value="Amazon.com" id="id3">Amazon.com</option>
</select>

<select name="vendor" id="vendor_select_from2">
    <option  value="Apple" id="id02">Apple</option>
    <option  value="Vector Resources, Inc" id="id12">Vector Resources, Inc</option>
    <option  value="Dell, Inc." id="id22">Dell, Inc.</option>
    <option  value="Amazon.com" id="id32">Amazon.com</option>
</select>
```

Thanks